# C#/.NET Service Bus using SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, event-bus

I know there are mature frameworks out there like NServiceBus, but I would like a queue that utilizes SQL Server and not MSMQ/RabbitMQ.

Is there one out there?

Answer (score 1):

You should look at ReBus. I have used it with SQL Server and worked fine.

https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at SQL Server [Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893%28v=sql.105%29) ?

I realise that an instance of SQL server running in some central location will never be a service bus. However, it's difficult to recommend anything without knowing what you're trying to use it for.

Answer (score 0):

Because of my interest in DDD, CQRS and Event Sourcing y studied the [CQRS Journey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554200.aspx) from Microsoft Patterns and Practices. Please, check the link. You will find an entire "tutorial" if you download the RI (Reference Implementation, which is basically the Demo App) and read along the articles, which is a book in reality. 
They implemented in Windows Azure, but, fortunately, they also included a version of the app with a custom Sql Server Bus. The implementation is very cool, even if they say that it should no be used in production I did it. And is working flawlessly. Hope this helps.

Comment: could You please give some throughput measurments, from your production env. if possible? for example your peak send/recieve msg per sec. ?

Comment: The source code of my own implementation you can find [here](https://github.com/Narvalex/EventCentric). You can distribute aggregates per node, per machine. It depends on your hardware, but it could be fast as thousands of messages per second.